# What is a good default PATH to use if none is defined by the environment?

Tags: shell

I'm making a small shell for a school project and I was searching about default `PATH`s. Say there is no `PATH` in the global `environ` variable, the various shells I tested always managed to search some default paths (sometimes unknown) to find the executable to run [`ls` is chosen as an example]:

Bash Shell behaves like so:

```
dflt-zsh > env -i bash
bash-3.2$ echo $PATH
/usr/gnu/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:.
bash-3.2$ ls
Makefile   shell.c   src   includes
bash-3.2$ export PATH=
bash-3.2$ ls
bash: ls: No such file or directory
```

C Shell seems to be lost when no PATH is defined but found the ls executable nonetheless:

```
dflt-zsh > env -i csh
% echo $PATH
PATH: Undefined variable.
% ls
Makefile   shell.c   src   includes
```

Z Shell has the most elements in `$PATH` but it may be reading some of my default zsh configuration files (not very trustworthy example):

```
dflt-zsh > env -i zsh
achedeuzot% echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin
achedeuzot% ls
Makefile   shell.c   src   includes
achedeuzot% PATH=
achedeuzot% ls
zsh: command not found: ls
```

TC Shell behaves as C shell.

```
dflt-zsh > env -i tcsh
> echo $PATH
PATH: Undefined variable.
> ls
Makefile   shell.c   src   includes
```

What is a good "default PATH" to search even if none is set ? I was going for something along the lines of `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:.`

How can I choose which directories to include by default ? Are there some crucial directories to search ? Main question: **Is it "choose what you like" or are there any basic rules that all the shells follow ?**

Thanks for your help !

Comment: The question as framed is too vague.  What is better? It just depends

Comment: I updated the question to emphasis that what I'm really searching for is if there is a basic rule for default PATHs that all shells follow or not...?

Comment: Most shells have a set of built-in commands. Use the which command to find out whether a command is a program or a built-in.

Comment: @luserdroog That's not the core of my question. Plus, when testing `which ls` on bash, csh, sh, zsh, it always points to `/bin/ls` so it doesn't seem built-in...

Comment: That's why I converted to a comment (and removed the false claim about `ls`). I see that it's not the core of the question, but it is pertinent, I think.

Comment: Ok, I didn't see the update, my bad ! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no universal solution.  On some systems, `/bin` is a symlink to `/usr/bin`, so adding just `/usr/bin` to `PATH` will get you most of the programs.  Adding `/usr/gnu/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` is optional; not all systems have either or both of those.  Sometimes people add `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin`.  The list of variations goes on.  The basic, minimal PATH setting is usually:

```
/bin:/usr/bin
```

Anything extra is precisely that — extra.  (And, as noted, on some systems, that is not a minimal PATH.)